# useTransition with react-spring as a component changes

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

I'm attempting to animate a card in and out. If there is a selected value, the card appears. If the selected item is undefined, the card disappears. I got this to work.

The next thing I tried to do is make it that if the selection changed (A new item) - animate out a card and animate in a new one. I'm confused on how to make this work... here is what I've attempted that kind of works.

Clearly I'm not understanding how this should be done. I'm wondering if I need to break this up into two cards and run useChain.

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

  //...

  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState<TimelineItem | undefined>(undefined);
  const [lastSelectedItem, setLastSelectedItem] = useState<TimelineItem>({
    content: '',
    start: new Date(),
    id: 0,
  });

 //...

  const transitions = useTransition(
    [selectedItem, lastSelectedItem],
    item => (item ? item.id : 0),
    {
      from: { opacity: 0 },
      enter: { opacity: 1 },
      leave: { opacity: 0 },
    }
  );

  return (
      <Timeline
        onItemSelect={item => {
          if (selectedItem) setLastSelectedItem(selectedItem);
          setSelectedItem(item);
        }}
      />
      {transitions.map(({ item, key, props }) => {
        return (
          item && (
            <animated.div style={props}>
              {item === selectedItem ? (
                <ItemDetails
                  item={selectedItem} // If the selected item is undefined, this will not be running (happens when unselecting something)
                  groups={groups}
                  key={key || undefined} // key becomes undefined since item is
                ></ItemDetails>
              ) : (
                false && ( // The last item never shows, it still has the data for the lastSelectedItem (For the fade out while the new Item is being shown or there is no new item).
                  <ItemDetails
                    item={lastSelectedItem}
                    groups={groups}
                    key={key || undefined}
                  ></ItemDetails>
                )
              )}
            </animated.div>
          )
        );
      })}
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well, you want to display the state of an array. New elements fade in and old one fades out. This is the functionality the Transition created for. I think it can be done a lot simpler. I would change the state managment and handle the array in the state. And the render should be a lot simpler.

**UPDATE:**
I created an example when the animation of the entering element wait for the animation of the leaving element to finish.
I made it with interpolation. The o value changes from 0 to 1 for enter, and 1 to 2 for leave. So the opacity will change:

leave: 1 -> 0 -> 0

enter: 0 -> 0 -> 1

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useTransition, animated } from "react-spring";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [cards, set] = useState(["A"]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      set(cards => (cards[0] === "A" ? "B" : "A"));
    }, 4000);
  }, []);

  const transitions = useTransition(cards, null, {
    from: { o: 0 },
    enter: { o: 1 },
    leave: { o: 2 },
    config: { duration: 2000 }
  });
  return transitions.map(({ item, key, props }) => (
    <div style={{ fontSize: "300px" }}>
      <animated.div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          opacity: props.o.interpolate([0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
        }}
      >
        {item}
      </animated.div>
    </div>
  ));
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-staggered-transition-xs9wy

Comment: The problem with this approach is the leave animation and the appear animation happen at the same time. And the two cards are side by side so it looks weird (I could change the position property to put them on top of each other... but I think it'd be awesome to have one leave, then the other enter). Thank you for the response!

Comment: When they are side-by side that sucks, but you can use absolute positioning, as you mentioned. This is usually the standard. It is not that bad in real life. For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/image-carousel-with-react-spring-usetransition-q1ndd or https://codesandbox.io/s/react-spring-page-transition-example-to-prevent-scrollbar-8uckc

Comment: So with the absolute... how do I make one effect go after the other is the main hangup. They both happen at the same time.

Comment: Yes they happen at the same time. You can shift the effects with interpolation, for the sake of excersie, but it is not really that different in real use. I updated the answer. I have to slow it down with time based animation to really see it. Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: Took me a while to understand this but it mostly solves it. Thanks for the help, you helped me understand opacity. Does this mean that the enter doesn't start on the first item showing until half of the total animation time is over? enter: 0 -> 0 -> 1. IE if the animation took 10 seconds, it would take 5 seconds to start animating on the first enter? I tested it, looks like it does.